# Java syntax methods and classes

Tags: java

I am very new to Java, and relatively new to programming.  I have 3 classes, that are connected.

*Class 1: Flight*

```
public class Flight {

    private int flightNumber;
    Passenger passenger1 = null; // two objects?
    Passenger passenger2 = null;
    private int confirmedPassengers = 0;
    Passenger bagsChecked;
    //private boolean bagsLoaded;


    public Flight(int fn, int cf){
        flightNumber = fn;
        //passenger1 = p1;
        //passenger2 = p2;
        confirmedPassengers = cf;
        //bagsChecked = bc;

    }


        public boolean addPassenger(Passenger p){
            if (confirmedPassengers == 0){
                passenger1= p;
                confirmedPassengers+=1;         
                System.out.println("P1 has been added.");
                return true;
            }   

            if (confirmedPassengers == 1){
                passenger2 = p;
                confirmedPassengers+=1;
                System.out.println("P2 has been added");
                return true;
            }

                else{
                    System.out.println("This passenger was not added because the capacity is full.");
                    return false;

                }
        }

    }
```

*Class 2: Passenger*

```
public class Passenger {

    private String name;
    Flight flight;
    private int bagsChecked;
    private String confirmationNumber;


    public Passenger(String n, Flight f, int b, String cn){
        name = n;
        flight = f;
        bagsChecked = b;
        confirmationNumber = cn;
    }

    public boolean hasConfirmation(){
        if (confirmationNumber != null) {
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

*Class 3: Kiosk:*

```
public class Kiosk {
    private int kioskNumber;

    public Kiosk (int k){
        kioskNumber = k;

    }


    public void checkIn(Passenger p){


        if (p.hasConfirmation() == true) {

            addPassenger(p); // trying to add Passenger here
            System.out.println("Passenger " + p.getName() + ""+ "added in at Kiosk1 ");


        }


    }
}
```

I am trying to add a `Passenger` to `Flight` when the passenger checks in at `Kiosk`. How can I use the `addPassenger` method in `Flight` to add `Passenger` to `Kiosk`?

Comment: What is the functionality of Kisok class ? Am i missing something?

Comment: Giving an advise because you are a beginner....
Whenever you take a reference, first check for `null`. Otherwise your program will crash. So, in `checkIn` method, you should put,
`if (p == null) {
     /* handle this situation */
}`

Comment: note that the as answer checked answer is not really nice to do. Read my answer why. Having a list is a good idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Kiosk.checkIn()`:

```
p.flight.addPassenger(p);
```

A few recommendations:

When you have a collection of things (like passanger1 and passanger2) you might want to use an array or better yet some form of [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) like `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Passanger> passangers = new ArrayList<Passanger>(2);

passangers.add(p);
System.out.println(passangers.size());
```

Also public data members are not very nice. Create setters and getters where you need them, so the code above whould rather look like this (after implementing `Passanger.getFlight()`:

```
p.getFlight().addPassenger(p);
```

Comment: @vbennce.. `ArrayList` would be a better option.. I think..

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of class Flight somewhere in the Kiosk, otherwise you won't be able to call its methods, ay?

Answer (score 0):

Use Composition

```
public class Kiosk { 

private int kioskNumber;
private Flight f;
private Passenger ps;

public Kiosk (int k){
    kioskNumber = k;

}


public void checkIn(Passenger p){


    if (p.hasConfirmation() == true) {

        f.addPassenger(p); // trying to add Passenger here
        System.out.println("Passenger " + p.getName() + ""+ "added in at Kiosk1 ");


    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (p.hasConfirmation() == true) {

    addPassenger(p); // trying to add Passenger here
    System.out.println("Passenger " + p.getName() + ""+ "added in at Kiosk1 ");
}
```

Your `addPassenger(p)` method is not static.. So you can't call it unless you have an instance of the class where it is declared..

In your `Kiosk` class, declare a reference to `Flight` class as an instance variable..
Then call `addPassenger()` on that instance..

```
private Flight flight = p.getFlight(); // Edited -- new Flight();
```

And your call to `addPassenger()` would be like this: -

```
flight.addPassenger(p);
```

You need to add a `List<Passenger>` in the class `Flight`.. So that you can maintain a list of all the passengers in that flight.. And use the above method, to add a `passenger` to the `flight`

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Import Flight Class into the Kiosk and make an Instance of that Flight Class into the Kiosk.
Now with the Instance of Flight Class You can access the method addPassanger.
jst **like Instance_Of_Flight_Class.Method_Name**

Answer (score 0):

```
// add a new method to Passanger class
public Flight getFlight() { return flight; }

// change how you use addPassanger() in Kiosk
if (p.hasConfirmation()) {
    Flight passangersFlight = p.getFlight();
    if (passangersFlight != null) {
        passangersFlight.addPassanger(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just edit the `checkIn(Passenger p)` method to have two parameters, since your `Kiosk` looks like some sort of Controller class:

```
checkIn(Passenger p, Flight f) { 
  if (f != null) f.addPassenger(p); 
}
```

?

You should avoid calling `addPassenger` through the `Flight` object referenced within the `Passenger` object, as someone else said, because you don't want the `Passenger` to have anything to do with his own addition to the `Flight`.

You *could, but shouldn't* add the `Passenger` through his own `Flight` reference. Have the `Passenger` have this code:

```
public boolean addMeToFlight() {
  return flight.addPassenger(this);
}
```

Then, you could call in `Kiosk`: `p.addMeToFlight();`.